# Testing REST endpoints with custom exception handling

Tags: java, testing, spring-boot, exception, mockmvc

I am working on a project with Spring microservices (modules) and I want to test my REST endpoint using `MockMvc`. My testing works fine for cases where the request is valid but it is not working when requesting a url that is invalid. By not working I mean my custom exception handler (`@ControllerAdvice`) does not get called, the exception gets thrown and the test fails.

My exception handler and testing class are implemented in different modules.

**common-module (ExceptionHandler)**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CoreExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessageDTO> handleException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) {

        // Getting servlet request URL
        String uri = request.getRequestURI();
        HttpStatus a;

        ErrorMessageDTO errorMessage;

        if (ex instanceof CoreException) {
            CoreException e = (CoreException) ex;
            ...
            errorMessage = new ErrorMessageDTO(e, uri);
        } else {
            errorMessage = new ErrorMessageDTO(ex, uri);
            ...
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorMessageDTO>(errorMessage, a);
    }
}
```

**country-module**

This is where my REST endpoint and Testing class are implemented. The common module dependency is included in this module's pom.xml and the packages are scanned through the main class.

**CountryApplication.java**

```
@EnableCaching
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
    "com.something1.something2.something3.common.exception",
    "com.something1.something2.something3.common.util.logged",
    "com.something1.something2.something3.country"
})
public class CountryApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(CountryApplication.class, args);
    }
    ...
}
```

**CountryService.java**

This is a method in my Service class.

```
@GetMapping("/{id:\\d+}")
public CountryDTO getCountryById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) throws CoreException {

    Country countryEntity = this.countryRepository.findOne(id);

    // requesting for id that does not exist
    if (countryEntity == null) {
        throw new CoreException(CoreError.ENTITY_NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return this.countryMapper.daoToDto(countryEntity);
}
```

**CountryServiceTest.java**

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class CountryServiceTest {
    ...
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void getByIdTest() throws Exception {

        // Get by id exists
        mockMvc.perform(get("/2"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(contentType))
            .andDo(print());

        // Get by id not exists. NOT WORKING
          mockMvc.perform(get("/100000"))
            .andExpect(status().isNotFound())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(contentType));

    }
}
```

As I described above, the problem is that at the second request of the test method, the `CoreExceptionHandler` does not get called and the test fails throwing a:

`NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.something1.something2.something3.common.exception.CoreException`.

The dependency for the common module is well configured (at least when I am deploying in non-test mode) since I am using it for other things too, plus the ExceptionHandler gets called when I am not testing.

Another strange thing is that when I am deploying my Test, Spring Boot's logs show that the `CoreExceptionHandler` gets detected. This is the line. `Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in coreExceptionHandler`

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems as explained below:

**(1)** ControllerAdvice not being set for `MockMvc` object in your `CountryServiceTest` class, which can be done as shown below:

```
MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(yourController)
        .setHandlerExceptionResolvers(new CoreExceptionHandler())
        .build();
```

**(2)** Because `CoreException` is wrapper by `NestedServletException` by the Spring Container, you need to use `exception.getCause()` to check your exception as shown below:

```
@ControllerAdvice
    public class CoreExceptionHandler {

        @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
        public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessageDTO> handleException(Exception ex, 
            HttpServletRequest request) {

            // Getting servlet request URL
            String uri = request.getRequestURI();
            HttpStatus a;

            ErrorMessageDTO errorMessage;

            //check with exception cause
            if (ex.getCause() instanceof CoreException) {
                CoreException e = (CoreException) ex;
                ...
                errorMessage = new ErrorMessageDTO(e, uri);
            } else if (ex instanceof CoreException) {
               //this block will be used only when direct CoreException triggered
                CoreException e = (CoreException) ex;
                ...
                errorMessage = new ErrorMessageDTO(e, uri);
            } else {
                errorMessage = new ErrorMessageDTO(ex, uri);
                ...
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<ErrorMessageDTO>(errorMessage, a);
        }
    }
```

**Also, I suggest not to handle all exception types in a single generic method, which will be very hard to support/maintain, rather split your `CoreExceptionHandler` using multiple `@ExceptionHandler` methods/classes.**

Comment: As I mentioned, the `handleException` method does not get called at all when testing.

Comment: I removed `@Autowired` from `MockMvc` and initialized it as you suggested in a `@Before` method. I still get the same error and the handler still does not get called.